# panic: interface conversion:Obj is not ObjInterface: missing method X

Tags: go

At the moment, I'm stuck in this code : https://play.golang.org/p/r_HEVmpOuD

```
package main

import "fmt"

type (
    Collection struct {
        Id string
    }
    CollectionInterface interface {
        Process(...string)
    }
)

func (this *Collection) Process(params ...string) {
    this.Id = "ok"

}

func testfunc(input interface{}) CollectionInterface {
    inputCol := input.(CollectionInterface)
    inputCol.Process()
    return inputCol
}

func makeInterface(input interface{}) interface{} {
    return input
}

func main() {
    test := Collection{Id: "ya"}
    test.Process()
    testInt := makeInterface(test)

    test0 := testInt.(CollectionInterface)
    test1 := testfunc(test0)
    fmt.Println(test1)
}
```

I'm just wondering how can I convert the interface{} into CollectionInterface without changing the "Process" function into a static function?

Comment: Add a `&` in line 31: Collection does not implement Collection Interface (only *Collection does). And: Take the Tour of Go once more.

Comment: I'm actually getting the interface from reflection, I just found out that the way to get it's pointer is using Add().Interface() function. I hope it helps people who stuck to get pointer for reflection interface.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line `test := Collection{Id: "ya"}` to this `test := &Collection{Id: "ya"}`. The interface is implemented for type `*Collection`; not `Collection`.

Comment: This is accurate.  The rule of thumb with interfaces is that value methods can fulfill the required interface methods for either a value or a pointer passed into the interface, but pointer methods can only fulfill the interface if a pointer is passed into the interface.  This is mostly because, if you passed in a value, it got copied when stored in the interface, so pointer methods wouldn't affect the original version you passed in, and thus aren't defined.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it wrong. I make little modification to fix it. Let me know if you have question.

https://play.golang.org/p/SEesgVhXt8

Comment: The thing is, I'm getting the interface{} from a reflection. Do you know how to get the pointer with reflection? (still trying to figuring out reflection)

Comment: Ok, I managed to figured it out. Using Add().Interface() give me the pointer that's the same with &variable... you are a legend, thank you very much.. been stuck in this issue for 3 days haha..

Comment: Bingo. Been looking for this for hours. Glad you commented what you found. For clarity, I think you meant `Addr()` so something like `reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(someVar)).Elem().Addr().Interface()`